# Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection error: Array index out of bounds

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code in Outlook to create a reply from the currently open email or the email that is selected.

This code has worked in the past but has stopped working because `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` no longer recognizes an open email.

A snippet of my code.

```
Public Sub ReplyWithAttachmentsTwo()
Dim rpl As Outlook.MailItem
Dim itm As Object
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objBkm As Word.Bookmark
 
Set itm = GetCurrentItem()
If Not itm Is Nothing Then
    Set rpl = itm.ReplyAll
    rpl.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    CopyAttachments itm, rpl
    Unload templateUserForm
    Unload inputUserForm
End If


Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
     
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
 
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

`Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)` is the problematic line. `GetCurrentItem` gets set to Nothing even when I have an email open. The `ActiveInspector` portion works fine.

Without `On Error Resume Next` I get

> Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)' Array index out of bounds.

Comment: Get rid of the "On Error Resume Next" line and see if you get back an exception.

Comment: I get Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)' Array index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there is an email open is not relevant. The code check first for the active window.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test_GetCurrentItem()

    Dim itm As Object
    
    Set itm = GetCurrentItem()
    
    If Not itm Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "itm identified."
    Else
        Debug.Print "itm Is Nothing."
    End If

End Sub


Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    
    Dim myFolderName As String
    
    Select Case TypeName(ActiveWindow)
    
        Case "Explorer"
        
            Debug.Print "ActiveWindow is an explorer."
            
            If Inspectors.Count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Open inspectors: " & Inspectors.Count
                Debug.Print "Open items are not relevant since the active window is an explorer."
                Debug.Print "If an open item is the required item, do not click elsewhere once you open it."
            End If
            
            On Error Resume Next    ' folder has no items or selection cleared.
            ' Not for unexpected errors.
            ' You have to know there could be an error and what it would be
            '  so you can deal with the error or purposely ignore.
            Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
            On Error GoTo 0         ' consider mandatory after On Error Resume Next
            
            If GetCurrentItem Is Nothing Then
                ' Deal with bypassed error
                Debug.Print "No selection in " & ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name
            Else
                Debug.Print "GetCurrentItem is a selection in " & ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name
            End If
            
            
        Case "Inspector"
        
            Debug.Print "ActiveWindow is an inspector."
            Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
            
            
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)' Array index out of bounds, that means `objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0`, which means nothing is selected.

Comment: I understand that, but my problem is that I don't understand why I'm getting that error because this code used to work. I have not changed the code so obviously something else has changed.

Comment: If there are no items in a folder, Selection.Count would be 0. You need to handle that scenario.

Comment: My mistake, ```Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveWindow.CurrentItem``` is the line that handles open emails. My problem remains the same though. When I run the code with an email open, the email is not recognized. I do not get an exception with that line of code.

Comment: But then how do you explain the error if you remove "On Error Resume Next"?

Comment: The error only happens on ```Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)``` when no item is selected in Outlook. If I comment that line out, the code still runs but ```GetCurrentItem``` gets set to Nothing.

Comment: Of course, you need to check that `objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection >0` first